# How to prevent GitHub project Issue to close automatically when pull request is merged/closed?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using the board of a Project (new) in GitHub.
When I have an Issue within a Pull Request linked to it and I close the Pull Request (using GitHub button at the bottom of the pull request page) the Issue is also closed.
I don't want this behavior, also if that is the only PR on the Issue.

I tried to change the project Workflow settings removing the "pull request" "is:closed"  trigger:

[image]

Initial state: both Issue and PR are open:
[image]

Merge the PR to master:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Also the Issue is closed !!
[image]

Comment: There was a request in the GitHub community... but ... no response:
https://github.community/t/feature-request-prevent-issues-from-being-closed-by-merging-linked-prs/3255

Comment: From what I can tell, there _is_ a response in the GitHub community, which is that they've added it to the feature backlog. Until they actually work on it, you probably need to create your PRs manually and make sure they're not linked to the issue.

Comment: I believe the main reason to link the PR to the issue is probably to see them "grouped" in the project board and also to have some behavior in the workflow.
Said that, it is still better to have to reopen the issue manually than loose this behaviours (but it really depends to why teams links the PR in first place).
You are right, there is a response (on May 2020) but it's worth to specify that it says this is added to the fetaure backlog, that's all. No response to them that asked for link/reference about it.